# "I should have been writing..." or "I will have been writing"

Tags: word-choice

**"I should have been writing..."** or **"I will have been writing..."**

I'm writing a book. There is a deadline for it. My sentence is:

"Until the deadline, two months from now, I should have been writing at least twenty-three pages."

Is there  anything better to say:

> "Until the deadline, two months from now, I will have been writing at
>   least twenty-three pages."

**EDIT:**

Thanks to FumbleFingers I edit my sentence to:

> By the time of the deadline, which is two months from now, I should
>   have written at least 23 pages in total.

Comment: I'm not clear on what meaning you want to convey (do you mean you *will* write 23+ pages, or just that you *ought to* write that much? In total, or per day?). None of your suggestions seem to make sense anyway (why have you included the word ***until**?*). Perhaps what you're trying to say is something along the lines of ***By the time of** the deadline, which is two months from now, **I will have written** at least 23 pages*. Or if it's just a hypothetical scenario (because you know that you're not going to do it, or that you ***might*** not do it), ***...I would have written...***

Comment: can you think about your tags. "I" "Should" "Have", "been"   are not good tags for this question.

Comment: *By the deadline, I **will have written** at least twenty-three pages.*

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't know "I will have written..." but "I should have written..." because of that I ultimately choose = By the time of the deadline, which is two months from now, I should have written at least 23 pages in total.